# Ensemble learning with time-varying covariates and effects

Tags: r, machine-learning, survival, random-forest, time-varying-covariate

We are interested in replicating several duration studies in the literature using ensemble learning methods. After some experimentation, we opted for random survival forests ([Ishwaran et al. 2008](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1645.pdf)) for their simplicity and performance. However, the package `randomForestSRC` in R only allows for time-invariant covariates. As one might guess, many interesting theoretical problems usually involve parameters that take on different values over time. Does anyone know how to implement TVCs in R using machine learning? We would prefer sticking to random forests, but naturally would switch if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 4):

The most widely used approach for survival analysis of time-varying covariates (TVCs) are Cox models. There you need to create a dataset with TVCs which is described in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf)

```
fit.cox <- coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ x), data = data)
```

However there is also the possibility to include TVCs in random survival forests. [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-019-0863-0) by Wongvibulsin, Wu, and Zeger (2019) extends the randomForestSRC package to handle TVC, but you may need to contact the authors for any relevant code.

Comment: There appears to be an implementation of RF-SLAM (algorithm described in Wongvibulsin, Wu, and Zeger 2019) here: https://github.com/mattrosen/rfSLAM

Comment: See also: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LTRCforests/